# What happens if an attacker and defender have exactly equal (net difference 0) final values for their attack and defense rolls?

Tags: combat, anima-beyond-fantasy

The title somewhat says it all...  What happens if an attacker and defender roll exactly equal values?  This actually *happened* to me in a test combat.  The other player and I mutually agreed nothing happened.

There's no entry on the Combat Table for it, this much I know.

Answer (score 1):

They are locked in combat no damage is dealt and the defender doesn't lose his attack action (if he has declared such).

Comment: Do you have a source for that?

Comment: For reference: (Attacker's total(after modifiers) - Defender's Total (after modifiers) -20 for absorption -10* AT of the defender of the attack type) /100 (making a percentage) * the final damage of the attacker's weapon.

If absorption is what stopped the attack then they are considered "Hit", and lose their action.

In the scenario you've made reference to, no counter attack are made, and it is not stopped by absorption.

The book states on page 81 that negative values result in counter attacks. It is not a positive value either, so no attack successfully lands. No actions lost.

Comment: @Riddley I know this comment's a bit late, but do you have a source for that?  Also, that's an answer.

Comment: Can you be more specific? I sourced it. The equation for determining an attack is from the core exxet. The book clearly states what occurs for both negative and positive results. Logically, neither occur in the situation of "0".